# Google Sheets - Add a formula to the drop down button that automatically copies data to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a script that I could input under the drop down button in a Google sheet.
The drop down has three options "not submitted", "in progress", and "submitted".

Most of the data on here makes use of a drawer button or form.

I just want to be able to **copy the data of a row automatically to another sheet when I toggle the submitted in the drop down button in that row**.

[image: a glimpse of what the rows look like]

Do you have any suggestions?

---

**Edit**
Basically from this sheet 1 to sheet 2 when submitted is toggled.

[image: Sheet 1]

to

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: Welcome. When you say *"transfer"*, could you probably mean *"copy"*?

Comment: I have data inputted in sheet 1 (row 2) together with a drop down box beside it that contains options. What I need is a script that could trigger the transfer of this data from row 1 to another sheet (sheet 2) when I toggle one option (submitted option) in the drop down box.

Comment: Yes, copy the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 but the data will not be cleared in sheet 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with regular formulas, in spreadsheet 2 you can set a formula like this `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("{Link of sheet 1}","A:D"),"Select * WHERE (Col4='Submitted')")`

That way it will pull the data from the range of spreadsheet 1 only where the value of the column 4 in your range is set to "Submitted".

But if you want to use Apps script you can use the [OnEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) so that it checks on every update and use the [values.Batchget method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) to get the values of the range on sheet 1, then check in the script if the value of the position of 4 in the range is equal to "Submitted" then use the [method values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) on spreadsheet 2

But I would suggest using the formulas as its way easier and doesn't require any programming

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a script for that.
You can achieve your desired result using a formula

```
=IF(Sheet1!D3="submitted",INDEX(Sheet1!A3:C3),Sheet1!D3)
```

Put this formula in the first cell and drag it down.

If you only want the data when "submitted" (and not the "in progress" or "not submitted"), use this formula.

```
=IF(Sheet1!D3="submitted",INDEX(Sheet1!A3:C3),"")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Did this formula not work for you?

Comment: it did but i tried the other suggested one and the summary sheet was cleaner (there was no blank rows in sheet 2 when i toggle submitted on sheet 1) works the same just wanted a cleaner look for sheet 2 since i'm planning to make it a summary of data :)